# Java doesn't work with regex \s, says: invalid escape sequence

Tags: java, android, regex, whitespace

I want to replace all whitespace characters in a string with a "+" and all "ß" with "ss"... it works well for "ß", but somehow eclipse won't let me use \s for a whitespace.. I tried "\t" instead, but it doesn't work either.. I get the following error:

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones
>   are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ )

this is my code:

```
try {
    String temp1 = from.getText().toString();
    start_from  = temp1.replaceAll("ß", "ss");
    start_from  = start_from.replaceAll("\s", "+");
}
```

why doesn't it work? is it a problem with android, eclipse or what?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm surprised that you can even compile \s in a string literal. Adding \t in a string literal would create a regular expression containing a tab character, rather than the regular expression with \t in it, for that you need \\t in the string literal.

Comment: I couldn't compile it,.. eclipse gave me this error message I posted. I just wanted to let you know what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to escape the slash

```
start_from  = start_from.replaceAll("\\s", "+");
```

Comment: thank you! awesome website! :-)  

"You cannot accept an answer in 11 minutes" .... ;-)

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that `\` is an escape character in java *as well as* regex patterns. If you want to match the regex pattern `\n`, say, and you'd go ahead and write

```
replaceAll("\n", "+");
```

The regex pattern would not end up being `\n`: it would en up being an actual newline, since that's what `"\n"` means in Java. If you want the *pattern* to contain a backslash, you'll need to make sure you escape that backslash, so that it is not treated as a special character within the string.

```
replaceAll("\\s", "+");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the java.util.regex.Pattern class and use something like `p = Pattern.compile("\s");` in combination with `p.matcher(start_from).replaceAll("+")`.  Alternatively, just escape your "\s" metacharacter as "\\s".

Comment: jepp I already used a pattern in another part of my code, however, I thought it would be easier in this case to just use replaceAll(..)
thank you!