# Regarding regex whitespace

Tags: java, regex

I have a small query regarding representing the space in java regular Expression.

I want to restrict the name and for that i have defined an pattern as

```
Pattern DISPLAY_NAME_PATTERN = compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.!~*()=+$,-\s]{3,20}$");
```

but eclipse indicating it as error "Invalid escape sequence".It is saying it for "\s" which according to

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

is a valid predefined class.

What am i missing.Could anyone help me withit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: then i am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 25
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.!~*()=+$,-\s]{3,20}$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java doesn't work with regex \s, says: invalid escape sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733255/java-doesnt-work-with-regex-s-says-invalid-escape-sequence)

Comment: @JoelBrewer no, escaping only won't solve his problem.

Comment: @AvinashRaj ahh. I see :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\` in `\s` one more time. And also, you don't need to escape the `.` inside a character class. `.` and `\\.` inside a character class matches a literal dot.

```
Pattern DISPLAY_NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.!~*()=+$,\\s-]{3,20}$");
```

And also put the `-` at the first or at the last inside the  character class. Because `-` at the center of character class may act as a range operator. `regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range` exception is mainly because of this issue, that there isn't a range exists between the `,` and `\\s`

If you want to do a backslash match, then you need to escape it exactly three times.

```
Pattern DISPLAY_NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.\\\\!~*()=+$,\\s-]{3,20}$");
```

Example:

```
System.out.println("foo-bar bar8998~*foo".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_.\\\\!~*()=+$,\\s-]{3,20}"));   // true
System.out.println("fo".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_.\\\\!~*()=+$,\\s-]{3,20}"));  // false
```

Comment: Now this is strange when i move "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.!~*()=+$,-\\s]{3,20}$" in last then i am getting exception but if i move it in middle then it is working fine.do you have any idea

Comment: What's the exception you got? You need to move `-` inside the charcater class from the middle to the last inside the same character class itself.